# How to inlclude JavaDoc for CPLEX API in a maven project?

Tags: maven, javadoc, cplex

How can I include the Cplex JavaDoc in my maven project to get code assistant on the Cplex Java API?

Comment: Do you have the javaDoc for a cplex.jar somewhere? Or do you ask how to get it?

Comment: Thank you for your very fast comment. I wanted to document the work flow that I just found for other CPLEX users. My own answer that follows below clarifies the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc can be found here:

{PATH_TO_CPLEX_INSTALLATION_FOLDER}/doc/html/en-US/refjavacplex/html/

For non maven projects you can reference that path directly in the project settings.

For maven projects you can put that files into a javadoc jar file: 
Open the CommandLine and navigate to the folder, e.g.

> cd C:/Program%20Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Enterprise_Server126/CPLEX_Studio/doc/html/en-US/refjavacplex/html/

Then create the javadoc jar file:

> jar cvf cplex-1263-javadoc.jar *

Then put the created javadoc jar next to the CPLEX library jar and a corresponding pom file in your local maven repository, e.g.

{PROJECT_ROOT}\maven_project_repository\ilog\cplex\1263\

- cplex-1263.jar
- cplex-1263-javadoc.jar
- pom.xml

The pom file is for example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ilog.concert</groupId>
  <artifactId>cplex</artifactId>
  <version>1263</version>
</project>
```

On an update of the Maven Dependencies the javadoc is automatically retrieved together with the API. Set the checkbox for downloading javadoc files in your maven settings if you use Eclipse:
[image]

Here are some snippets for including the local maven repository and the CPLEX dependency:

```
<repositories>

        <!-- Custom In-Project repository that contains dependencies that can not 
            be found on maven servers -->
        <repository>
            <id>maven_project_repository</id>
            <name>Maven Project Repository Share</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/maven_project_repository</url>
        </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
<!-- cplex -->
        <dependency> <!-- from in project maven repository -->
            <groupId>ilog.concert</groupId>
            <artifactId>cplex</artifactId>
            <version>1263</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This answer is confirmed by this [thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014849301) on the IBM developerWorks forum.